# How to build this request query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to fill a column with two different data one by one using sql request 
exp:

My_Table1

```
## CL1 ##  ## CL2 ## ## CL3 ##
---------- ---------- ---------- 

 - DATA1   X1           
 - DATA2   X2
-  DATA4   X3
 - DATA5   X4
     *     *
     *     *
 - DATA200 X200
```

Table_2

```
## CLX ##  
---------- 
  are you under 20 yeras old ?
  are you male or female ?
```

I want the result be like that:

```
## CL1 ##  ## CL2 ## ## CL3 ##
---------- ---------- ---------- 

 - DATA1   X1           are you under 20 yeras old ?
 - DATA2   X2           are you male or female ?
-  DATA4   X3           are you under 20 yeras old ?
 - DATA5   X4           are you male or female ?
     *     *
     *     *
 - DATA200 X200         are you under 20 yeras old ?
```

How will be using SQL request ? databae is Oracle

Comment: You can try to use a while loop in the sql

Comment: how can you give me a sample example ?

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without more details.  What is the structure / model of your database.  What data does it contain (input)  What is the expected output. I understand you have input and output in your question but that does not help... since there is no way to understand how one is derived from the other.  Is it just 3x what is in the table?

Comment: just so I understand, you want the results to be assigned in "order" what is the order asc on CL1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CL1, CL2, CLX
FROM (SELECT CL1, CL2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CL1 ASC) AS RN
      FROM My_Table
     ) AS T1_WITH_RN
JOIN (SELECT CLX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CLX DESC) AS RN
     ) AS T2_WITH_RN ON MOD(T1_WITH_RN.RN, 2) + 1 = T2_WITH_RN.RN
```

How this works

- First use a query with the window function ROW_NUMBER() to assign an incrementing integer to the query result
- Then we do the same for table two (we expect only two values for RN here 1 and 2) and join them on the row number of the first table mod 2 plus one (which will have values 1 or 2)

---

Based on what you show we can't really answer your question.  For example this will do what you ask for  -- taking the data in a column and repeating it 3 times

```
SELECT column_Text FROM table
  UNION ALL
SELECT column_Text FROM table
  UNION ALL
SELECT column_Text FROM table
```

Comment: ok i'll explain with deatails: let have table has 200 records and 11 column the last one i want to is servey column should be like this are you male or female ? and the next record are you under 20 yeras old ? one by one till the last record

Comment: same thing like that  : INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (select distinct my_colmn from table1)

Comment: @Yassine -- still have no idea what you mean -- **you have to post the data model, example input, and example output** (Additional information which clears up details can also help.)

Comment: randomly without order

Comment: @Yassine ok posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.*,
       t.clx
FROM   ( SELECT m.*,
                ROWNUM AS rn
         FROM   My_Table1 m ) m
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT t.*,
                ROWNUM - 1 AS rn,
                COUNT(*) AS mx
         FROM   Table_2 t ) t
       ON ( MOD( m.rn, t.mx ) = t.rn );
```